# Calling `~` with the prefix convention

Tags: r

This works

```
lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)
```

So does this:

```
lm(`~`(mpg, cyl), mtcars)
```

But this does not:

```
lm(base::`~`(mpg, cyl), mtcars)
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  argument is not a valid model
```

Why does the third case fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem stems from the `terms()` function. You get the same error from

```
terms(base::`~`(mpg,cyl))
```

That can be traced back to the [C source for that function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ed66b715221d2720f5b334470335635bada520b1/src/library/stats/src/model.c#L1665) which does

```
tildeSymbol = install("~");

if (!isLanguage(CAR(args)) ||
CAR(CAR(args)) != tildeSymbol ||
(length(CAR(args)) != 2 && length(CAR(args)) != 3))
error(_("argument is not a valid model"));
```

so it's literally looking for a `~`, not a `~` prefixed with a namespace. The `CAR` functions in this case act kind of like this

```
quote(`~`(mpg,cyl))[[1]]
# `~`
quote(base::`~`(mpg,cyl))[[1]]
# base::`~`
```